Matrix subset selection
We aim to select rows and columns of any matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.
Define a selection matrix $\mathbf{S}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ where $S(i,j)=x_i \cdot y_j$, the matrix after selected is given by
$$\mathbf{A}_s = \mathbf{S} \odot \mathbf{A}$$
where $\odot$ denotes Hadamard product, the sum of the selected rows and columns is $\gamma(m + n)$ (where $1>\gamma>0$). The formulation of this problem is given by
\begin{aligned}
& \min_{\mathbf{S}} & & \| \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{S} \odot \mathbf{A} \|_F^2 \\
& \text{Subject to} & & S(i,j)=x_i \cdot y_j \\
& & & \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i + \sum_{j=1}^{n} y_j = \gamma(m + n) \\
& & & x_i \in \{0, 1\}, \, i = 1, \ldots, m \\
& & & y_j \in \{0, 1\}, \, j = 1, \ldots, n \\
\end{aligned}
How to solve the problem above?

You can linearize $S(i,j)=x_i\cdot y_j$ by $$\begin{aligned} & s_{i,j} \le x_i \\ & s_{i,j} \le y_j \\ & s_{i,j} \ge x_i+y_j-1 \\ & s_{i,j} \in \{0,1\} &&\text{(can be relaxed to be continuous)}\end{aligned}$$ The objective can be made quadratic (by dropping the square root). We now have a convex MIQP (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming) model. Solvers for these types of models are readily available.

Thanks， the problem is further modified as:
\begin{aligned}
& \min_{\mathbf{S}} & & | \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{S} \odot \mathbf{A} |F^2 \
& \text{Subject to} & & \sum{i=1}^{m} x_i + \sum_{j=1}^{n} y_j = \gamma(m + n) \
& & & S(i,j)\leq x_i,  \
& & & S(i,j)\leq y_j, \
& & & S(i,j)\geq x_i+y_j-1,\
& & & S(i,j) \in {0, 1}, , where , i = 1, \ldots, m ,, and , j = 1, \ldots, n,
\end{aligned}
I know some libraries can solve this problem, but as a convex optimization problem, is it possible to directly derive an analytical solution? I tried, but I couldn't succeed.

Most non-trivial models need to be solved numerically.
